# records saved in mongodb disappeared after some minutes

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Updated records got missing after awhile in mongodb

I tried to update a document in mongodb using java driver 3.6, st first the records got updated successfully. but after 1 minutes those records value turned to an empty string

```
A = new A();
            BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("username", username);
            BasicDBObject updateFields = new BasicDBObject();
            updateFields.append("fullnames", agent.getFullnames());
 BasicDBObject setQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            setQuery.append("$set", updateFields);
            getLiveagentCollection().update(searchQuery, setQuery);
```

The updated records shoould remain persisted on the DB

Comment: If you have index in your DB you should check if you have TTL configured in some of them.

Comment: Yes I have index in my DB, So how do I check the TTL configuration

Comment: Do you use MongoDB Compass? If yes, open the collection, go to tab "Indexes" and in the column Properties you will see if one of them has TTL configured.

Comment: Thank you Nadal, the Properties column is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue, by adding writeconcern within the mongodb.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27112);
client.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY);
```